# iOS delegate Cancel call fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I've got two view controllers, `HomeViewController` and `AddViewController`. `HomeViewController` is the delegate of `AddViewController`.

Problem is that when I hit the "Cancel" button in `AddViewController`, the call back to the delegate seems not to execute. Symptomatically, the Cancel button behaves as if it were not even wired up. Programmatically, breakpoints seem to indicate that control leaves the `cancelButton` method, yet never reaches `addViewControllerDidCancel`.

I believe everything is wired properly, and here's the relevant code:

From AddViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WMDGCategory.h"
#import "WMDGActivity.h"
@class HomeViewController;


@protocol AddViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) addViewControllerDidSave;

-(void) addViewControllerDidCancel:(WMDGActivity *) activityToDelete;

@end

@interface AddViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AddViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

From HomeViewController.h:

```
@interface HomeViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,AddViewControllerDelegate>
```

From HomeViewController.m:

```
-(void) addViewControllerDidSave
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self refreshData];

}

-(void) addViewControllerDidCancel:(WMDGActivity *) activityToDelete
{
    [activityToDelete MR_deleteEntity];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self refreshData];

}
```

And from AddViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)cancelButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self.delegate addViewControllerDidCancel:self.thisActivity];
}
```

Can someone spot my mistake?

Thanks!

**Edit in response to answer 1 below:**

Actually, I did this in my prepareFroSegue method in HomeViewController:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
        NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addModal"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        AddViewController *avc = (AddViewController *)navController.topViewController;
        avc.delegate = self;
        WMDGActivity *addedActivity = (WMDGActivity *)[WMDGActivity MR_createInContext:localContext];
        avc.thisActivity = addedActivity;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using a segue to display the AddViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your missing assigning the delegate object of your AddViewController instance, from what I can see it's still `nil`

```
myAddViewController.delegate = self;  // 'self' is an example, should be myHomeViewController instance
```

EDIT:
You are calling this in your code:

```
[self.delegate addViewControllerDidCancel:self.thisActivity];
```

Ask yourself what is the value of `delegate`? You have declared it, yes, but you have not set its value, so it must be `nil`. So when you instantiate your `AddViewController` you must set the delegate using the line I wrote before.

Comment: A very common problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following. Can you mod the code I included?

Comment: Please see my edit above. I believe it fulfills this requirement, no?

Comment: OK, problem solved. Puzzlingly, however, it doesn't seem to have been related to the one you pointed out. In fact, I didn't change anything there, just checked to see if things were as you suggested, which they were. However, it started crashing. I traced the crashed to a misnamed entity in my store. Many thanks for pointing out the instantiation issue, and I'll keep an eye on that in future!